# About part proof of Fortunate conjecture.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

6 years ago, I and my friend part prove this conjecture.

This conjecture prove by 2 steps.

I and my friend prove first step.

I want to announce our part proof.
What should I do.

The following Fortunate conjecture

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortunate_number

Comment: Write it out in pdf and publish it on arxiv.Use mathematics stackexchange to verify parts you are not sure of.That seems like a reasonable path to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your proof in [Latex](https://www.latex-project.org/)
and submit it to the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/)
.After these two steps submit it for publication in a journal.Even ifit does not prove the conjecture it will not be off-value(If it is correct).